# Log4j2: Programatically remove the existing appenders and add new RollingFileAppender dynamically for all loggers

Tags: logging, log4j2, rollingfileappender

We have a requirement to add the rolling file appender programmatically in application startup.
And also I need to remove the existing appenders(which are configured from log4j2.xml file).
I tried various approaches, but it didnt worked for me.

The problems I'm facing now are:

1. Some logs are still coming to the old appenders.
2. If I update logger level(from **INFO** to **DEBUG**) for any logger package those things also not coming properly.

```java
        LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        Configuration configuration = loggerContext.getConfiguration();

        //Removing the existing appenders
        configuration.getAppenders().keySet().forEach(((AbstractConfiguration)configuration)::removeAppender);
        
        String rollingAppenderName = "RollAppender";
        RollingFileAppender rollingFileAppender = RollingFileAppender.newBuilder()
                .setConfiguration(configuration)
                .setName(rollingAppenderName)
                .setLayout(layout)
                .withFileName("/tmp/test.log")
                .withFilePattern("/tmp/test.%i.log")
                .withPolicy(SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy("10MB"))
                .build();
        rollingFileAppender.start();
        configuration.addAppender(rollingFileAppender);

        /*
         * Updating appenders of all the loggerConfigs configured in the log4j2 config file.
         * */
        LoggerConfig rootLogger = configuration.getRootLogger();
        

        Map<String, LoggerConfig> loggerMap = configuration.getLoggers();
        for (LoggerConfig loggerConfig : loggerMap.values()) {
            AppenderRef appenderRef = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef(rollingAppenderName, loggerConfig.getLevel(), loggerConfig.getFilter());
            AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[]{appenderRef};
            if (Objects.equals(loggerConfig.getName(), rootLogger.getName())) {
                loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.RootLogger.createLogger("true", loggerConfig.getLevel(),
                        Boolean.toString(loggerConfig.isIncludeLocation()), refs, null, configuration, loggerConfig.getFilter());
                loggerConfig.addAppender(rollingFileAppender, loggerConfig.getLevel(), loggerConfig.getFilter());
            } else {
                loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger(true, loggerConfig.getLevel(), loggerConfig.getName(),
                        Boolean.toString(loggerConfig.isIncludeLocation()), refs, null, configuration, loggerConfig.getFilter());
            }

            configuration.removeLogger(loggerConfig.getName());
            configuration.addLogger(loggerConfig.getName(), loggerConfig);
        }

        loggerContext.updateLoggers();
```

Answer (score -1):

The approach you are taking is incorrect. Trying to manipulate the existing configuration in the way you are will result in log events being lost while you are messing with the configuration.  Instead, create a new configuration and once it is constructed replace the old configuration with the new one.

Comment: Here I'm updating the existing configuration because, I dont want to miss/loose all the configuration details coming from the log4j2.xml file.

Comment: Then copy what you want into the new configuration. But be aware, you may have to clone some of them as they may be stopped when the old configuration shuts down.

Comment: If I were doing what you say you want I would read the original Log4j2.xml file, remove the appenders and add your new one as xml and the reconfigure with that. Removing and adding xml is easy with xslt, although these days it is a bit of a lost art.

Comment: Yes @rgoers, I'm also looking for this kind of configuration. Can you elaborate your approach. And also one point we dont have any constraint over the file type(.xml or .properties or .json or .yml)

Comment: OK. for that you should create a new configuration using the original configuration file by calling ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration() with the appropriate parameters and then modify it as you had planned except you should not start any components and  replacing any AppenderRefs with ones that point to your Appender. Once it is modified pass it to LoggerContext's reconfigure(configuration) method.